# Read All File Names from a .rar File in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, archive, rar, winrar

I have an express route, that uploads files, that are sent to the server via `formData`.

Supposing the file is a `.rar` file, my goal is to extract all file names, that are inside this archive or it's subfolders.

This is how my express route currently looks like:

```
module.exports = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers })
        busboy.on('finish', async () => {
            const fileData = req.files.file
            console.log(fileData)
            // upload file
            // send back response
        })
        req.pipe(busboy)
    } catch (err) { return response.error(req, res, err, 'uploadProductFile_unexpected') }
}
```

Here is what the `console.log(fileData)` looks like:

```
{
    data:
        <Buffer 52 61 72 21 1a 07 01 00 56 0c 22 93 0c 01 05 08 00 07 01 01 8d d6 8d 80 00 85 76 33 e4 49 02 03 0b fc d4 0d 04 b1 8c 1e 20 bc 86 da 2e 80 13
    00 2b 66 ... >,
    name: 'filename.rar',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'application/octet-stream',
    truncated: false,
    size: 224136
}
```

Inside `filename.rar` are a few files like `texture.png` and `info.txt`. And my goal is to fetch those names.

Comment: Perhaps use this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rar

Comment: Would you please give an example on how to do this in regard to my prerequisites?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I eventually found an solution using [node-unrar-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-unrar-js):

```
const unrar = require('node-unrar-js')

module.exports = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers })
        busboy.on('finish', async () => {

            const fileData = req.files.file
            const extractor = unrar.createExtractorFromData(fileData.data)
            const list = extractor.getFileList()
            if (list[0].state === 'SUCCESS')
                //  Here I have the file names
                const fileNmes = list[1].fileHeaders.map(header => header.name)
                // ...

        })
        req.pipe(busboy)
    } catch (err) { return response.error(req, res, err, 'uploadProductFile_unexpected') }
}
```

Comment: This looks good!  I just thought I'd mention that usually you'd want to be saving these files anyway, usually with `busboy.on('file')` event handler.  Your example is clean, but if it's possible for the files to be large (more than few MB), IMO it's actually safer to pipe all files through busboy into temp files and then extract from the tempfile, rather than trying to keep the file in-memory in the node process.

Comment: Actually, that makes sense! It would be cool if you could post an example :)

Answer (score 0):

Use: `npm i node-rar`

```
const rar = require('node-rar')

rar.list('path/to/file.rar', 'optional password')
```

Reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rar

Comment: But where to get the path from when I only have the Buffer of the file available?

Comment: You might be a little out of luck in that department,something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/decompress will take a Buffer but it has no rar support. It seems you're going to have to write the buffer to disk first, use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/temp-write and then plug in that filepath.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [decompress](https://github.com/kevva/decompress) which accepts `Buffer` as an argument:

```
const Busboy = require('busboy');
const decompress = require('decompress');

module.exports = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers })
        busboy.on('finish', async () => {
            const fileData = req.files.file
            console.log(fileData)
            // upload file
            // send back response

            decompress(fileData, 'dist').then(files => {
                req.send(files.map(f => f.path))
            });
        })
        req.pipe(busboy)
    } catch (err) { return response.error(req, res, err, 'uploadProductFile_unexpected') }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `files` is always an empty array

Comment: You sure `decompress` supports `.rar`, not just `.zip`? From [this](https://github.com/kevva/decompress/issues/59) open ticket, I'd assume it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Steps could be:

```
npm install -g node-rar
```

or

```
npm install node-rar
```

and

```
node-rar --version
```

in your file:

```
var rar = require('node-rar');

/// list archive entries
rar.list('path/to/file.rar', 'optional password');
// => [entries]

/// test archive entries
rar.test('path/to/file.rar', 'dir/to/test', 'optional password');
// => [entries]

/// extract archive entries
rar.extract('path/to/file.rar', 'dir/to/extract', 'optional password');
// => [entries]
```